# Ao selecionar o chekbox preciso que a frase fique tachada. Segue img exemplo

Tags: html

Design a nice theme
                  
                   2 mins

Make the theme responsive
                   4 hours

Let theme shine like a star
                   1 day

Let theme shine like a star
                   3 days

Check your messages and notifications
                   1 week

Let theme shine like a star
                   1 month

```html
<ul class="todo-list">
                <li>
                  <!-- drag handle -->
                  <span class="handle">
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                      </span>
                  <!-- checkbox -->
                  <input type="checkbox" value="">
                  <!-- todo text -->
                  <span class="text">Design a nice theme</span>
                  <!-- Emphasis label -->
                  <small class="label label-danger"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 2 mins</small>
                  <!-- General tools such as edit or delete-->
                  <div class="tools">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                      <span class="handle">
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                      </span>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="">
                  <span class="text">Make the theme responsive</span>
                  <small class="label label-info"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 4 hours</small>
                  <div class="tools">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <span class="handle">
                    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                  </span>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="">
                  <span class="text">Let theme shine like a star</span>
                  <small class="label label-warning"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 1 day</small>
                  <div class="tools">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <span class="handle">
                    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                  </span>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="">
                  <span class="text">Let theme shine like a star</span>
                  <small class="label label-success"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 3 days</small>
                  <div class="tools">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <span class="handle">
                    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                  </span>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="">
                  <span class="text">Check your messages and notifications</span>
                  <small class="label label-primary"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 1 week</small>
                  <div class="tools">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span class="handle">
                      <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                      <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                    </span>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="">
                  <span class="text">Let theme shine like a star</span>
                  <small class="label label-default"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 1 month</small>
                  <div class="tools">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
```

[image: Imagem modelo de como deverá ficar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Também dá para fazer pelo JavaScript manipulando a propriedade [`textDecoration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration)

```js
document.getElementById('texto').style.textDecoration = "line-through";
```

```html
<span id='texto'>Esse texto vai ser riscado!!!</span>
```

No seu exemplo:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]').forEach((elemento) => {
  elemento.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    var span = e.target.parentNode.querySelector('.text');
    span.style.textDecoration = (e.target.checked) ? "line-through" : "";
   
  });
});
```

```html
<ul class="todo-list">
  <li>
    <!-- drag handle -->
    <span class="handle">
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                      </span>
    <!-- checkbox -->
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <!-- todo text -->
    <span class="text">Design a nice theme</span>
    <!-- Emphasis label -->
    <small class="label label-danger"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 2 mins</small>
    <!-- General tools such as edit or delete-->
    <div class="tools">
      <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="handle">
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                      </span>
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <span class="text">Make the theme responsive</span>
    <small class="label label-info"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 4 hours</small>
    <div class="tools">
      <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="handle">
                    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                  </span>
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <span class="text">Let theme shine like a star</span>
    <small class="label label-warning"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 1 day</small>
    <div class="tools">
      <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="handle">
                    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                  </span>
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <span class="text">Let theme shine like a star</span>
    <small class="label label-success"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 3 days</small>
    <div class="tools">
      <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="handle">
                    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                  </span>
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <span class="text">Check your messages and notifications</span>
    <small class="label label-primary"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 1 week</small>
    <div class="tools">
      <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="handle">
                      <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                      <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                    </span>
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <span class="text">Let theme shine like a star</span>
    <small class="label label-default"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 1 month</small>
    <div class="tools">
      <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Executei com o js e funcionou muito bem. Grato!

Answer (score 0):

Se baseando na sua marcação, pode-se usar a regra `input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .text` para definir a estilização do elemento com classe `text` quando o checkbox próximo estiver checado:

```css
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .text {
  color: #ccc;
  text-decoration: line-through
}
```

```html
<ul class="todo-list">
  <li>
    <!-- drag handle -->
    <span class="handle">
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                      </span>
    <!-- checkbox -->
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <!-- todo text -->
    <span class="text">Design a nice theme</span>
    <!-- Emphasis label -->
    <small class="label label-danger"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 2 mins</small>
    <!-- General tools such as edit or delete-->
    <div class="tools">
      <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="handle">
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                      </span>
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <span class="text">Make the theme responsive</span>
    <small class="label label-info"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 4 hours</small>
    <div class="tools">
      <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="handle">
                    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                  </span>
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <span class="text">Let theme shine like a star</span>
    <small class="label label-warning"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 1 day</small>
    <div class="tools">
      <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="handle">
                    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                  </span>
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <span class="text">Let theme shine like a star</span>
    <small class="label label-success"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 3 days</small>
    <div class="tools">
      <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="handle">
                    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                  </span>
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <span class="text">Check your messages and notifications</span>
    <small class="label label-primary"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 1 week</small>
    <div class="tools">
      <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="handle">
                      <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                      <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                    </span>
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <span class="text">Let theme shine like a star</span>
    <small class="label label-default"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 1 month</small>
    <div class="tools">
      <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```